# Should I use xml for a simple restaurant website with 3 languages?

Tags: html, xml

I'm trying to build a website and the menu is in 3 language with the same prices and number order ex. 1.  General Tao 8.95$. Is it a bit overkill to use xml for the menu? because I know I can reuse it in indesign for printing the menu.

It's also important to have the .html extension instead of .xml, is there a way to do that without server side? I'm a bit confuse with xml, since i'm new to it. For the explanation please be detail enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you can reuse it, and its meeting your needs to build a flexiable menu system with 3 languages then go for it.

I dont quite understand what you mean by having .html instead of .xml. If your loading an xml file normally the extension would be .xml..

Comment: because Google rank well marked up HTML higher than XML documents, so I like to use xml with an html extension. Is this even possible? Because I built my web page in one single page with 4 different area (intro, home, menu and contact) the only place that I need xml is only on the menu area. Im not sure if I can like just fill out the place where I need the xml data.

Comment: Ah okay I see. What you have to do is make the html page load the xml file, using javascript or something then populate the menu with the data loaded from the xml file. Think of .xml as just a data file, and not something that actually gets rendered by the browser. The .html file is what will be rendered.